# Work with string in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp, string-length

This code works fine:

```
(let* ((str (read-line)))
      (write (char str 1)))
```

But if I add some, it breaks:

```
(let* ((str (read-line))
       (str-len (length str))))
      (write (char str 1)))

*** - EVAL: variable STR has no value
```

Why?

Comment: Your parentheses are wrong. You should have your editor indent the code for you to avoid that kind of problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`let` and `let*` introduce bindings in a set of forms with the following syntax:

```
(let bindings
  declarations 
  forms)
```

So the bindings have the value specified only inside the forms.

You have written:

```
(let* ((str (read-line))
       (str-len (length str))))
      (write (char str 1)))
```

If we align it to make it more understandable, it is simply:

```
(let* ((str (read-line))
       (str-len (length str))))
(write (char str 1)))
                    ^
                    | invalid parenthesis
```

So, you can discover that you have the `forms` part of the `let*` empty, which is legal in Common Lisp, and its value is `nil`.

You can also discover that the `write` form is *outside* the `let*`, and for this reason, the variables `str` and `str-len` are unknown, since they are outside of the global `let` form.

As specified in a comment, if you use an editor which knows the syntax of Common Lisp (there are several available), you can find this kind of errors as soon as you type your code. For instance, in this case you would have noticed immediately the extra parenthesis, which is highlighted clearly by such an editor. Moreover, the editor would have aligned correctly the forms, with `write` aligned under `let*`.